# Infer generic parameter from an array of types

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Fruit<T extends string> { type: T; }
class Apple implements Fruit<"apple"> { type = "apple"; }
class Orange implements Fruit<"orange"> { type = "orange"; }

const fruitTypes = [ Apple, Orange ];
```

How can I extract a type that is `"apple" | "orange"` from `fruitTypes`?

My best attempt was:

```js
type FruitTypes = InstanceType<typeof fruitTypes[number]> extends Fruit<infer U> ? U : never;
```

Which unfortunately yields `never`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt yields 'string', not never.

See [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DAHgCrIQAekIAJgM7IVhSgDmAfMgN7JgCeADhAFzJ4A3MgC%20AKAQAbOBSoBBLl0kpgAWyURVEcFXRZcAIjiLlB5m049kAXmRGTEA8PFSZVAPJQ4IeivXKtHTRMbBwDAHsvH0dzdm4UWwio3ydRMQlwkBpkGBCwPHiqWwBtZAUNABpkT29fZABdQXTLFD1sAp4i5ABJLLBvJA6IHBbwmBy8oYpikAxVACNoeuZiUkpg-RxQGGhkAFVmAH595H4QCAA3aEEgA).

I believe the problem lies not in the definition of `FruitTypes` type, but in definition of your classes.

With your code, TS complains:

```
(property) Apple.type: string
Property 'type' in type 'Apple' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Fruit<"apple">'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"apple"'.
```

If you change it to:

```ts
interface Fruit<T extends string> { type: T; }
class Apple implements Fruit<"apple"> { type: "apple" = "apple"; }
class Orange implements Fruit<"orange"> { type: "orange" = "orange"; }
```

this error goes away, and `FruitTypes` is correctly inferred to `"apple" | "orange"`

[TS Playground - corrected code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DAHgCrIQAekIAJgM7IVhSgDmAfMgN7JgCeADhAFzJ4A3MgC%20AKAQAbOBSoBBLl0kpgAWyURVEcFXRZcAIjiLlB5m049%20RkxAPIAvMhsaDw8VJlUA8lDgh6FXVlLR00TGwcAwB7PwC7c3ZuPmdY-0D7Jxi4jPcxCWiQGmQYCLA8ZKonAG1kBQ0AGmRfdJQAXUF8yxQ9bAqeKuQASSKwfyR%20iBxu6JgSssmKapAMVQAjaDbmYlJKcP0cUBhoZABVZgB%20M%20R%20EAgAN2hBIA)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem.
We make use of `Distributive property` of conditional types and `infer` the type from each of `Fruit<T>`

```
interface Fruit<T extends string> { type: T; }

let Apple : Fruit<"apple"> = { type: 'apple' }
let Orange: Fruit<"orange"> = { type: 'orange' }



const fruitTypes = [ Apple, Orange ];

type FruitTypes = 
  | typeof fruitTypes extends Array<infer K> 
    ? K extends any 
      ? K extends Fruit<infer T> 
        ? T 
        : never
      : never 
    : never


// type FruitTypes = "apple" | "orange"
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DAHgCrIQAekIAJgM7IVhSgDmAfMgN7JgCeADhAFzJ4A3MgC%20AWABQkgDYQwyAIJcus5P3RZcAIjjLZW5gF5W7bn2QByXSogXRMucgDyUOCHrmN2HFoD2r9wgDZGM2Th5%20C383DztxKQTJBF8QGmQYTGw8MypjAG1FPQgAGmcAj2QAXUFJSXCULzBsnlzkSWRkAB9THl8YdMymnMISCHIqBShXDhxQGGhkAGlmdo7kAH4lkdJKZDcONok1tc3F7bHdxtmQeagBFaPjk4FDp7X%20EAgAN2hV44-vgs-mpkJ8flBagkAPRQnoNQbNCCtHRFLRdZB%20cpBIA)

Comment: but Apple and Orange is not a class here, in question it uses class

Comment: You cannot use class as value inside the array right?
You will need to create an object from it, and then use it as value inside an array,
That's exactly what I have done

Comment: OP didn’t clarify if he uses classes as value inside array